# Randomly assigning new XY locations

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I have two shape layers, one containing 93 points and the other layer containing 15075 points. I am trying to randomly assign a new XY position for each of the 93 points to any of the 15075 point locations in the second layer.

I have tried using the create random points tool, but this only lets me generate random points from the 15075 know points. I would like to move each of my 93 points from the first layer to a random location on the second layer so that I can measure the distance moved.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Do you need the random selections to be independent like dice rolls or unique like a lottery draw? In other words, should it be possible for two start points to have the same randomly selected destination?

Comment: Assuming your 15k point data set is random you could do a spatial join using closest relationship? Whilst each join is a consistent relationship (e.g Closest) if the underlying data is randomly distributed I would have thought that would have achieved what you desire?

Comment: Two points should not have the same randomly selected destination

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches you can use here. The first (and probably the easiest) is to generate a number of sample object IDs from your candidate points layer, grab the associated geometries, shuffle the order, and then apply the results to your input points. For example (I'll assume your input points are `input_points` and your candidates are `candidates`):

```python
import arcpy
import numpy as np

num_inputs = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(input_points).getOutput(0))
num_candidates = int(arcpy.GetCount_management(candidates).getOutput(0))

# replace with np.random.randint(num_candidates, size=num_inputs) if you want repetition
ids = np.random.choice(num_candidates, size=num_inputs, replace=False)

# Limit the points queried from the dataset with the where clause
where_clause = "{oid_field_name} in ({ids})".format(
    oid_field_name=arcpy.Describe(candidates).OIDFieldName,
    ids=", ".join(str(i) for i in ids)
)

candidate_shape_field = arcpy.Describe(candidates).shapeFieldName

# Get the actual geometries
geoms = np.random.permutation([
    row.getValue(candidate_shape_field)
    for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(candidates, where_clause)
])

# Finally, update the original dataset (BACKUP BEFORE TRYING THIS AT HOME!)

input_shape_field = arcpy.Describe(input_points).shapeFieldName

cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor(input_points)

for geom, row in zip(geoms, cursor):
    row.setValue(input_shape_field, geom)
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

The second (which I think is a bit more interesting) is to use [reservoir sampling](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/04/hadoop-stratified-randosampling-algorithm/) to select n random points. Rather than re-implementing this yourself you could use the [algorithm from Austin Rochford's post] to generate samples like so:

```python
import itertools as itl

def sample_after(stream, k):
    """
    Return a random sample ok k elements drawn without replacement from stream.

    This function is designed to be used when the elements of stream cannot
    fit into memory.
    """
    r = np.array(list(itl.islice(stream, k)))

    for t, x in enumerate(stream, k + 1):
        i = np.random.randint(1, t + 1)

        if i <= k:
            r[i - 1] = x

    return r

geoms = sample_after(
    (
        row.getValue(candidate_shape_field)
        for row in arcpy.SearchCursor(candidates)
    ),
    num_inputs
)

for geom, row in zip(geoms, cursor):
    row.setValue(input_shape_field, geom)
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```